# Detect whether authetication credientials are already linked or not in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

**In Firebase,** I want the users to be able to sign in with providers like Facebook, Twitter, and Google but not to sign up with them. So, when the user tries to login with them, **how can I detect whether his/her credentials are linked to an account or not before trying to sign in with those credentials to Firebase?!**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is going to be possible. To be able to link accounts with those providers, you'll need to enable the providers in the Firebase console. And once you do that, users can call the API themselves to create an account with that provider.

---

If you don't care about this out-of-bounds abuse, and just want to make it work in your application code, have a look at the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`  method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail).

Comment: Alright, but the thing is that the app is supposed to be able to detect which account the credentials are linked to automatically without the user having to enter it the account email or phone number